# Keeping a part of a Subversion repository, but there is a path change in the middle

Tags: svn

I have a Subversion repository where a directory was moved once. I want to send
to someone only a part of the repository, which includes this
directory.

I believe I have read and understood [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s03.html).

What I tried:

```
svnadmin dump /home/Subversion-Repository | \
   svndumpfilter include new-name /new-name /foo/bar/old-name > something.svn

svnadmin create /new/repos
# Create directories foo/bar and new-name
svnadmin load /new/repos < something.svn
```

But it fails:

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 5944
svnadmin: File not found: transaction '5944-4l4', path 'new-name/myfile'
     * editing path : new-name/myfile ...
```

What surprises me is that, in the full dump (without going through
svndumpfilter), there is a revision which adds the files at the new
place:

```
Node-path: new-name
Node-kind: dir
Node-action: add
Prop-content-length: 10
Content-length: 10
```

but svndumpfilter does not keep it. So, the first revision mentioning
a file under new-name is 'Node-action: change' and not 'Node-action:
add' and it fails. Why?

An Unix shell script to reproduce the problem at will is [available](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/files/subversion-filtering-problem.sh).

[I asked the question on the Subversion mailing list but the message was not distributed, probably eaten by an overzealous spam filter.]

UPDATE: I tested Insyte's suggestion. Both svndumpfilter2 and
svndumpfilter3 fail. Both do not even check the argument, you can give
them a non-existing repository, they would not complain.

With svndumpfilter2, modifying [my script](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/files/subversion-filtering-problem.sh) to use `${SVNDUMPFILTER2} ${REPOS} other/new-name/bar foo/old-name/bar > ${DUMP}`:

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 7
svnadmin: File not found: transaction '8-8', path 'other/new-name/bar/myfile'
     * editing path : other/new-name/bar/myfile ...
```

With svndumpfilter3,  modifying [my script](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/files/subversion-filtering-problem.sh) to use
`${SVNDUMPFILTER3} --untangle=${REPOS} other/new-name/bar
foo/old-name/bar > ${DUMP}`:

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 7
svnadmin: File not found: transaction '8-8', path '/other/new-name/bar/myfile'
     * editing path : other/new-name/bar/myfile ...
```

Comment: Just so I'm getting it straight... you created a repo _foo_ and have _foo/old-name_ and _foo/stuff_ . You then rename _foo/old-name_ to _foo/new-name_ and want to export the repo and only pass along _foo/new-name_ and not _foo/stuff_?

Comment: Correct. See the script http://www.bortzmeyer.org/files/subversion-filtering-problem.sh for the complete list of actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have a now a solution which works, tested on a real
repository. The idea is to dump only revisions until (and not including) the
renaming, then the revisions after it (with the `--incremental`
option). Then, I reload the first dump, I do a renaming in the new
repository, and I reload the second dump. It seems to work properly.

I made a [modified version of my script](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/files/subversion-filtering-solution.sh) which show the detailed
steps.

If I understand properly, the original issue was that the renaming
took place at a higher level in the tree than the directories I wanted
to keep and so was not kept by svndumpfilter. Therefore, the
operations on files after the renaming failed because the nodes in the
dump were of type `change` and there was no node of type `add` for the
new location.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're encountering a variant of the `svndumpfilter: Invalid copy source path` problem.  This problem occurs when one of the directories/files included by svndumpfilter originally was copied (or, in your case, moved) from a section of the tree that is *not* being included.  The original solution to this was Simon Tatham's 
[svndumpfilter2](http://svn.tartarus.org/svn-tools/svndumpfilter2?view=markup) but his svn server seems to be down at the moment.

A slightly modified version is available here:
http://www.dehora.net/hg/tools/raw-file/tip/svn/svndumpfilter2

Another variant here:
http://furius.ca/pubcode/pub/conf/bin/svndumpfilter3.html

And another here:
http://www.undersea.com/~nmb/svndumpfilter4

with explanation for svndumpfilter4 here (from archive.org - unfortunately the original is no longer accessible):
http://replay.waybackmachine.org/20080827213200/http://www.undersea.com/~nburrell/blog/node/81

The variants are smart enough to use svnlook to retrieve the necessary source material even if it lives outside the included section of the tree.

Comment: I will try with the tools you suggest. I am not convinced yet since, in my case, both the old and the new subtrees are included by svndumpfilter. Only the moving/renaming revision is not (because it is higher in the tree).

Comment: `svndumpfilter4` dies right away with an idention error.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try out [dumpsanitizer](https://github.com/dsuni/svndumpsanitizer). It handles the problem cases where files/directories have been moved, without having to do it manually. We used this approach to set part of an older repository as a baseline for a new repository.